# Debugging Teamcenter Rich Client (eclipse rcp) fails with "org.osgi.service.component.ComponentException"

Tags: eclipse, debugging, teamcenter, teamcenter-rac

On a Windows 7 x64 machin I have a working eclipse installation and workspace, from which I run/debug plugins for the Teamcenter rich client  (which runs on Eclipse 3.6) flawlessly.

Now I moved eclipse and the workspace into another Windows 7 x64 machine, ensuring that I

- have the same version of the JRE
- have the same config and install paths
- have the same target platform (Teamcenter) install (at least the same set of plugins)

But there **on the new machine**, when I launch the debug configuration, the application fails to start with this exception:

```
org.osgi.framework.ServiceException: Exception in org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService()
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.getService(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:447)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.getService(ServiceRegistry.java:430)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.getService(BundleContextImpl.java:667)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.util.OSGIUtil.getService(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.util.OSGIUtil.getService(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.Application.runApplication(Unknown Source)
    at com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.Application.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1383)
Caused by: org.osgi.service.component.ComponentException: The component was not built because some of its references could not be bound. The component is Component[
    name = com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.RCPPortal
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp.RCPPortal
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [com.teamcenter.rac.services.IPortalService]
    references = {
        Reference[name = ISessionService, interface = com.teamcenter.rac.services.ISessionService, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = setSessionService, unbind = null]
    }
    located in bundle = com.teamcenter.rac.aifrcp_9000.1.0 [594]
]
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:342)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.ServiceReg.getService(ServiceReg.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse$1.run(ServiceUse.java:120)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceUse.getService(ServiceUse.java:118)
    ... 20 more
```

On that second machine I also tried using other eclipse releases and JREs, and exporting/importing the plugin project on a clean install, without success.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was in the `.target` file I used to specify the target platform (Teamcenter in this case).

Assume my `plugins` folder is in the path `C:\plm\plmsw\tcroot\portal\plugins`.

Eclipse accepts in the .target file both the forms:

1. Plugins Location = `C:\plm\plmsw\tcroot\portal\plugins`
   [image: Teamcenter target in eclipse (incorrect version)]
2. Plugins Location = `C:\plm\plmsw\tcroot\portal`
   [image: Teamcenter target in eclipse (correct version)]

But at runtime, **only the seconds is correct** because it is taken as the base path for the rich client.
The error originates from Teamcenter not finding the `registry` folder, that is searched in `C:\plm\plmsw\tcroot\portal\plugins\registry` and not in its correct location `C:\plm\plmsw\tcroot\portal\registry`